# Segmentation fault when trying to assign new value to my pointer

Tags: c

```
char *c = "H'eLo";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (isupper(c[i]))
    {
        c[i] = tolower(c[i]);
        printf("%c \n", c[i]);
    }
}
```

So I am running this code, and trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. What is the reason for the segmentation fault?

Comment: Change `char *c = ...` to `char c[] = ...`.  The reason the pointer version doesn't work is you have a pointer to a string constant, which cannot be modified.  Changing it to a statically initialized array will fix it.

Comment: You make `c` point to a string constant. Then you try to modify the thing `c` points to. But, by definition, you can't modify a constant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to modify the string, you should allocate it dinamically just like this

```
    char *c = malloc(5*sizeof(char));
```

Then, pass the string with strcpy

```
    strcpy(c, "H'eLo");
```

Or you also can do it with the function strdup, which is the easiest option

```
    char *c = strdup("H'eLo");
```

These examples should work, because C doesn't let you modify strings literals

---

Comment: It simply isn't allowed to modify string literals in C, so it's not a matter of recommendation, but instead requirement :-) Even if it doesn't crash sometimes, it gives the program undefined behaviour, so it can fail in baffling ways later.

Comment: Thanks !! I will add this to the answer

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: char *c = strdup("Hello World")

Comment: This writes out of bounds. as well as using redundant cast

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys !!